# Vlookup DragDown

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im beginning a new job in a fabric. Actually, for each product, they have a excel file with the product operations in different sheets. I saw that a real problem, it takes a lot of time, and every time we should have to change the layout of the order, we are going to need to change a lot of excel files.. It will take forever and I think I can help on that.

So, my idea, is making a sheet with all the products and their operations and formulas:

[image]

Then, I have maked another sheet with the order fabrication with all the operations needed to make the product:

[image]

Every product will have an ID and im using in all cells the vlookup function from the ID:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($K$3;'estrutura-artigos2'!B8:V71;5;FALSE);"")
```

And Its Ok like you see on the last image, the problem is when I change the ID it doenst change like it should be (on my head):

[image]

Can anyone help me on this problem? I want it to change always to the ID I insert, and dont continue with the new ID.

Comment: If the id is in k3 then k4 etc then remove the dollars so K3 not $K$3 and add dollar signs to the range. Then it will drag down.

Comment: No, K3 is the cell where I want to change the ID, in other words, the only cell it can change is the ID cell, when I put a value it will get the correct ID from the article.

Comment: @soldcarvalho Are you saying that you want the second image to say "33,333" in the 2nd and 3rd rows instead of "303"?

Comment: My english really is making thing hard to understand and for that im sorry. Well, when I change the ID from the second and third image, I want it to get all the values of the first image that has the same ID and put it on the rows of the second image erasing all the values that might be there from other ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!E:E;MATCH(1;($K$3=Sheet1!$A:$A)*(COUNTIF($A$6:$A6;Sheet1!$E:$E)=0);0));"")`

As your examples show no columns or rows I made my own. Please modify the formula to your ranges. Sheet1 is your datasheet.
Column A in Sheet1 is the column holding the ID in your datasheet.
Column E in Sheet1 is the column holding the 'op' in your datasheet (between qty and machine column).
Counting starts at row 6 in my example, but modify it to the cell above where you put your formula.

Enter the formula with `ctrl+shift+enter` as it is an array formula.

Change the index for the different results, but keep the rest of the formula unchanged.

Updated answer based on the visibility in rows and columns:
In A13 use `=IFERROR(INDEX(datasheet!F$8:F$72;MATCH(1;($K$3=datasheet!$B$8:$B$72)*(COUNTIF($A$12:$A12;datasheet!$F$8:$F$72)=0);0));"")`
Match returns the row number of the first match where datasheet column B equals the value in $K$3 and where the values of datasheet column F don't equal any of the previous results of this formula in column A (above the current row number)
The result is the row number that needs shown from the indexed column.

Comment: Hello P.b, before anything I want to thank you for helping. Im trying that formula and it makes something (finally), but now im having the problem that its going to the operation 20 in the first now, instead of the 10. Any idea why im having this issue?  My formula right now is this one: =IFERROR(INDEX(datasheet!G:G;MATCH(1;($K$3=datasheet!$B:$B)*(COUNTIF(datasheet!$B$8:$B72;datasheet!$F:$F)=0);0));"") *Im going to update the images

Answer (score 0):

For the issue im having, this is as far I already went thanks to @P.b:

[image]

[image]

The problem im having is that the formula Im using goes right no operation 20, instead going to the operation 1, any idea how to fix this?

Formula using on the A13 = =IFERROR(INDEX(datasheet!F:F;MATCH(1;($K$3=datasheet!$B:$B)*(COUNTIF(datasheet!$B$8:$B71;datasheet!$F:$F)=0);0));"")

Comment: I updated my answer to match your data, please try it out.

Comment: Its working! Thanks a lot! The problem now is that this formula and the way Im inserting the data is quite heavy. Its taking a lot of time to process when I change the ID. Any idea how to optimize the formula or how to process faster? If not, It doesnt matter, even if I cant optimize it im proud of this really good work thanks to you P.b

Comment: By changing the data ranges in datasheet to start and end cell (for example `datasheet!F$8:F$71`). It's important that the start cell of the ranges in datasheet are in the same row.

Comment: it is this what you mean? =IFERROR(INDEX('datasheet'!F:F;MATCH(1;($L$4='datasheet'!$B:$B)*(COUNTIF($B$13:$B13;'datasheet'!F$8:F$71)=0);0));"") ... I have done that for the first row, For the next rows it gives me different results

Comment: No, check the updated answer: `=IFERROR(INDEX(datasheet!F$8:F$72;MATCH(1;($K$3=datasheet!$B$8:$B$72)*(COUNTIF($A$12:$A12;datasheet!$F$8:$F$72)=0);0));"")`

Comment: If your index of datasheet starts at row 8, your match(es) range in that sheet should start at row 8 as well

Comment: Done! It is really faster right now. Million thanks P.b! You really helped me a lot man! You are no doubt a excel professional!

Comment: P.b. Just one question if it isnt too much to ask. What if I want just to find in the "operation" column just one type of machine? For example, I want to make one worksheet with just machine1, other with machine2 and other with machine3. Any hint?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Instead of getting all data from the product in the datasheet, I want it to the get only the data refering to one type of machine in the operations column. In the first image, there is machine1, machine2, machine3, I want to get only the row refering to machine2 for example. Do you understand? (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: Than add another cell containing the machine you want shown and add another co signing to the match function like this: `MATCH(1,(CELL1=RANGE1)*(CELL2=RANGE2)*(CELL3=RANGE3),0)`

Comment: Done it. With that I really understood the meaning of match and how to work it that formula. Again, lot of thanks.

Comment: Great. Glad I could help.